# An equation skip problem --- amsmath package and \above/belowdisplayskip

Tags: spacing, equations, line-spacing

I have been puzzled by a problem about math equation skip for days. I set the `\lineskiplimit`, `\lineskip`, `\abovedisplayskip` and others length macros before and after equations all to zero, but there has still some skip (see pic). I wanted to know how to get rid of these skip.

There is the code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[margin=2in]{geometry}
\begin{document}
\setlength{\lineskiplimit}{0pt}
\setlength{\lineskip}{0pt}
\setlength{\abovedisplayskip}{0pt}
\setlength{\belowdisplayskip}{0pt}
\setlength{\abovedisplayshortskip}{0pt}
\setlength{\belowdisplayshortskip}{0pt}\noindent
Some text some text some text some text some text 
some text
\begin{equation*}
a+b=c
\end{equation*}
Some text some text some text some text some text some text
\begin{equation*}
1^2+2^2+\dotsb+n^2=\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}
\end{equation*}
Some text some text some text some text some text some text
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Very strange request  but you need (perhaps) `\baselineskip=0pt` but it's not easy to use it at only some places.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[margin=2in]{geometry}
\begin{document}
 \setlength{\lineskiplimit}{0pt}
 \setlength{\lineskip}{0pt}
\setlength{\abovedisplayskip}{0pt}
\setlength{\belowdisplayskip}{0pt}
\setlength{\abovedisplayshortskip}{0pt}
\setlength{\belowdisplayshortskip}{0pt}    
\noindent
{\baselineskip=0pt
AAAA BBBBB  AAAA BBBBB AAAA BBBBB AAAA BBBBB 
\begin{equation*}
a+b=c
\end{equation*}
AAAA BBBBB  AAAA BBBBB AAAA BBBBB AAAA BBBBB 
\begin{equation*}
1^2+2^2+\dotsb+n^2=\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}
\end{equation*}
AAAA BBBBB  AAAA BBBBB AAAA BBBBB AAAA BBBBB }
\baselineskip=10pt plus 2pt minus 3pt
AAAA BBBBB  AAAA BBBBB AAAA BBBBB AAAA BBBBB 
\begin{equation*}
a+b=c
\end{equation*}
AAAA BBBBB  AAAA BBBBB AAAA BBBBB AAAA BBBBB
\begin{equation*}
1^2+2^2+\dotsb+n^2=\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}
\end{equation*}
AAAA BBBBB  AAAA BBBBB AAAA BBBBB AAAA BBBBB
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @gerx348 The problem is not the equations but the text around. Some skips are used to format lines, paragraphs etc.

Comment: @altermundus if the skip is make because text around, why the second equation can get rid of the skip?

Comment: @gerx348 I'm not a great TeX expert but I suppose that the skips are elastic as `\baselineskip=10pt plus 2pt minus 3pt`. This explains to TEX that it should put 10pt (maybe up to 2pt more, maybe up to 3pt less) of glue between the baselines of two consecutive lines in a paragraph (this may depend on `\lineskiplimit`). Now you need to know the exact mechanism of a lot of things to make what you want. The second equation is higher and with your constraints, the space above is (seems) to be null. I think others skips are used and you need to control all the skips.

Comment: @gerx348 You make a mistake with the second equation because with your code if you put SSSS above the equation there is no space.

Comment: @Altermundus: `\showthe\baselineskip` shows that `\baselineskip` is _not_ elastic.

Comment: @Hendrik I see nothing with `\showthe\baselineskip`. Perhaps don't use the good term (bad english) but if I write `\baselineskip=10pt plus 2pt minus 3pt` I can't say that `\baselineskip` is elastic ? The Textbook says : it's preferable to work with  `\baselineskip` not elastic but  it's possible. No ?

Comment: @Altermundus: `\showthe\baselineskip` writes `12.0pt` to the terminal. Of course you _can_ change `\baselineskip` to anything you want; I only meant the `\baselineskip` in the OP's MWE.

Comment: @Hendrik Ok! yes you are right, this is the default in this case and it's possible to change the value locally. But I think that a lot of skips are (or can be) elastic because TeX needs some helps to construct lines, pages etc.

Comment: @Altermundus: It depends on the subject. If you're typing a _novel_, a nonelastic `\baselineskip` is important: If you turn pages, you'll usually want the baselines of the reverse side match with those on the front side of the page. (Whatever the correct terminology is here.) But you're right, most other skips are flexible for better page construction.

Comment: @Altermundus Thanks for your nice solution. @ Hendrik vogt Thank you too.

Comment: @Hendrik: That would be grid typesetting. It's a real pain to do in LaTeX, but I've had some success with it recently which I keep meaning to finish writing up.

Comment: @TH: Yep, but if it's a novel, it's not _that_ hard. You won't have that many things that are different from simple lines.

Comment: @Hendrik: True. Although dealing with widows and orphans is still a huge hassle. The novel I'm currently reading doesn't bother fixing them. (I could just imagine the reaction an author who has just written 250k words would have when told some text needed to be changed to fix orphans. =)

Comment: @TH. Where could I find your book or manual's link about the "grid typesetting“? I am very interested in it!

Comment: @gerx348: I'm afraid I haven't written up much about it at all. http://texhacks.blogspot.com/search/label/grid Maybe I'll write more later this week. I've been busy lately.

Comment: @TH. Anyway, thanks for your efforts on the problem!

Comment: @TH: Right, I forgot about those - a hassle indeed.

Answer (score 1):

Under usual circumstances you shouldn't *want* to get rid of that skip. Altermundus told you how you *can* do it, namely by setting `\baselineskip=0pt`, but you see that the result is rather ugly. The reason for the skip is that the standard `\baselineskip` is `12pt`, and you can check that the distance between the baselines is exactly `12pt` in lines 1--3.

So why is there no skip around the second formula line? The point is: `\baselineskip=12pt` means that the distance of the baselines has to be *at least* `12pt`, and you get that distance from the large fraction already, so TeX doesn't have put an additional skip.

Comment: vogt I just want all the equations in document have the same sep (above or below) with texts. I think, as in the example Altermundus given, that change the `\abovedisplayskip` and `\belowdisplayskip` to 6pt is better than the default appearance (like my pic).

Comment: @gerx348: Ah, now I see what your aim is - with positive `\abovedisplayskip` and `\belowdisplayskip` it sounds quite reasonable. But you should take something strechable, e.g. `\abovedisplayskip=6pt plus 2pt minus 1pt`.

Comment: Yes, I set the `\abovedisplayskip` to zero just for clarity.

Answer (score 1):

```
Some text some text some text some text some text some
Some text some text some text some text some text some
Some text some text some text some text some text some
Some text some text some text some text\par\nointerlineskip
\vbox{\baselineskip=0pt\centering
\[a+b=c\]}\nointerlineskip
\noindent Some text some text some text some text some text some text
```

Other solutions, such as setting `\baselineskip=0pt`, have the defect that all the paragraph will be typeset with that parameter, with no separation between lines. Setting only `\lineskip` is also not a solution, as it will give uneven spacing between lines.

Comment: Thank you for the better solution. But I think the vbox cannot handle as `\begin{align*}a&=b\\c&=d\end{align*}` situation which could break page between the lines.

Comment: Of course not. But if you assign it to a box register, you can measure it and even split it. As you see, grid typesetting involving displayed math formulas is quite hard.