# Vertical Spacing - blkarray environment inside align environment

Tags: vertical-alignment, align, blkarray

I have created my own command that creates labelled column vectors using the [`blkarray`](https://ctan.org/pkg/blkarray?lang=en) environment. Vertical spacing issues arises when the command is used inside the `align` environment. It generated too much vertical space.

I have used `\\[-3em]` right after `\begin{align}` and just before `\end{align}`; but I don't want to adjust it manually every time. Moreover, I took a look at [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/21679/167081), but the problem still persists.

[image: Output]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{blkarray}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\newcommand{\colVectorLabelled}[2]{
  \ensuremath{\mathrm{#1} = 
    \begin{blockarray}{*{1}{c} l}
      \begin{block}{*{1}{>{$\footnotesize}c<{$}} l} & \\\end{block}
      \begin{block}{[c]>{$\footnotesize}l<{$}}#2\end{block}
    \end{blockarray}    
  }    
}
\begin{document}

  \textbf{The} \verb|\blockarray| \textbf{environment alone}: Some filler text
  some filler text some filler text some filler text some filler text some filler text.\\
  \colVectorLabelled{X}{1 & $0_{2}$\\0 & $1_{2}$\\}

  \textbf{The} \verb|\blockarray| \textbf{environment inside} \verb|\align| 
  \textbf{environment}: Some filler text some filler text some filler text some 
  filler text some filler text some filler text.\\
  \begin{align}
    \colVectorLabelled{X}{1 & $0_{2}$\\0 & $1_{2}$\\}
  \end{align}
  More filler text filler text filler text filler text filler text filler text filler text
\end{document}
```

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is is workaround, with `\useshortskip` from `nccmath` for the above spacing, and a simplle `\vskip -2ex` for the space below:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{blkarray}
\usepackage{amsmath, nccmath}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\newcommand{\colVectorLabelled}[2]{
  \ensuremath{\mathrm{#1} =
    \begin{blockarray}{*{1}{c} l}
      \begin{block}{*{1}{>{$\footnotesize}c<{$}} l} & \\\end{block}
      \begin{block}{[c]>{$\footnotesize}l<{$}}#2\end{block}
    \end{blockarray}
  }
}

\begin{document}

  \textbf{The} \verb|\blockarray| \textbf{environment alone}: Some filler text
  some filler text some filler text some filler text some filler text some filler text.\\
  \colVectorLabelled{X}{1 & $0_{2}$\\0 & $1_{2}$\\}

 \textbf{The} \verb|\blockarray| \textbf{environment inside} \verb|\align|
 \textbf{environment}: Some filler text some filler text some filler text some
 filler text some filler text some filler text some filler text some filler text some filler text.\useshortskip
 \begin{align}
 \colVectorLabelled{X}{1 & $0_{2}$\\0 & $1_{2}$\\}
 \end{align}\vskip-2ex
 More filler text filler text filler text filler text filler text filler text filler text

\end{document}
```

[image]